# How was a form of a Latin word chosen for deriving an English word?

Tags: etymology, latin

Sometimes I was wondering why a word in English was derived from a form of a Latin word, and how the form was chosen.

For example, from etymology online, I learned that
ignite (v., "kindle or set on fire, cause to burn," "catch fire, begin to burn") was derived from Latin ignitus, past participle of ignire "set on fire, make red hot".  Why was past participle instead of other forms of ignire chosen to derive ignite?

Comment: My guess is that it comes down to how Latin spread into Germanic areas. Latin was spread by the Roman empire as they conquered territory, but like in any imperialistic expansion, the people who were now forced to learn and use it may not have learned it fully or very well. One common side effect of this is simplification, where different words merge together. So maybe some group knew the word ignitus and used it more and more until it was the most common form of the verb in a certain context.

Comment: Insufficiently specific.    There were *a lot* of loan words, and some weren't even chosen but sort of drifted into usage, and others were chosen by a lot of different people who had varying motives in their choice -- and semantic drift would hit after.

Comment: The OED suggests the reason is unkown, but offers a couple of theories. *"Origin: Either formed within English, by conversion. Or a borrowing from Latin. Etymons: ignite adj.; Latin ignīt-. Etymology: < ignite adj., or Latin ignīt- participial stem of ignīre to set on fire, < ignis fire"*.  The reason they mention *"by conversion"* is because the first attestations of the word "ignite" in English are actually as an adjective which meant "intensly heated, white hot, glowing  with heat". However the adjective form is now obsolete, and the verb form is first attested over 100 years later.

Comment: Not sure if I should really add this as an answer here, because the etymology tag says these kind of questions are more suited to the English Language & Usage Stack Exchange.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on english.stackexchange.com

Comment: The question isn't logical - words weren't 'chosen'. The language wasn't created by some council who thought this Latin word sounded nicer than the Germanic alternative. Sometimes there is a historical explanation for the etymology of specific words, but often there is not. But as a very, very general rule of thumb, because Latin was only spoken by educated people, words relating to academic subjects or just things that did not concern common people are more likely to be derived from it.

Comment: There are many different ways that words came from Latin into English: via vulgar Latin and old French; via Germanic languages (whether to Anglo-Saxon or via the Franks to French); as later borrowings from medieval Latin directly into English or via French; a few from other Romance languages (e.g. siesta from sixta hora); or occasionally through even more tortuous ways. And as mentioned, sometimes as a noun, other times as a verb or adjective. We can track this (see e.g. the OED). But the question of why a word took a particular route is not subject to general laws.

Answer (score 2):

Language is not always consistent and therefore a rule when to use which form to derive from cannot be given. It would have at least as many exceptions as cases covered and would be useless.

There are even words derived from different forms of the same original word:

> "ferre" = to carry

The verb *ferre* is an irregular word, the perfect ("i have carried") is "tuli", the perfect participle is "latus" ("carried"). From the present tense there is "transfer" ("trans-"="over", "transferre" "to carry over"), while "translate"/"translation" is from the past participle "translatus" ("the carried over").

Also

> "ire" = to go

"exitus" (gone out) is from the perfect participle but "expire" from the present tense "ex-(p)-ire".

Sometimes, though, the way the form was chosen fits. An example would be

> "agere" = to do, to further

which is in "agitation" and "agent" ("agens" is the present participle, "doing") but also "action" and "act", because the PPP (perfect participle passive) is "actus" (the "done").